# Batch file that doesnt run

Tags: batch-file

I have creted a batch file that I want to run the SetupCodeGroup.exe
When I double click the batch file it doesnt run the exe file. A command prompt opens up but it doesnt run the file. Can someone tell what I missed or what I am missing

```
C:\Users\raw008\Desktop\Critcare\SetupCodeGroup.exe
```

Comment: What operating system are you running this on?

Comment: Answer: start /d "C:\Users\raw008\Desktop\Critcare" SetupCodeGroup.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type `pause` on the next line and check whether this executable comes on the command prompt .
try

```
start C:\Users\raw008\Desktop\Critcare\SetupCodeGroup‌​.exe
```

moreover

```
start /d "path_to_file_directory" program.exe
```

is the complete line to execute program and console will not wait to program to exit .

Comment: I did and this is what I get C:\Users\raw008\Desktop\Critcare>C:\Users\raw008\Desktop\Critcare\SetupCodeGroup.exe

Comment: try start C:\Users\raw008\Desktop\Critcare\SetupCodeGroup‌​.exe and pause

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this exe requires administrative privileges. Try right-clicking the batch file and running it as administrator.

Comment: If you open a command prompt and, then run the batch file from the prompt it will give you an error message.

Comment: no error. I opened a command prompt dragged the .bat into the black window and it just displayed whats inside the file

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

start C:\Users\raw008\Desktop\Critcare\SetupCodeGroup‌.exe

echo Done
pause
```

try that if that dose not work then your computers privleges are messed up, i ran into the same problem on my cousins computer.